# How to post a text in twitter as a hyperlink in iphone?

Tags: iphone, twitter, hyperlink

I want to post a text in a twitter as a hyperlink.I am able to post it as a simple text message.I have used Twitter+OAuth.i have used

```
[_engine sendUpdate:@"My twitter update"];
```

method to post my content.How can post is as a hyperlink so clicking on text opens a link.Any ideas? 
Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what the question is. What do you want the hyperlink to do? Open a webpage in Safari? Open an app on the iPhone? Post a link to Twitter?

Comment: @Moshe--> post a link on the twitter

Answer (score 5):

You can not post hyperlinks on twitter, however you can post URLs which will then be converted to hyperlinks (but with the complete address as name). You can accomplish this by posting the full URL with the "http://"